# Notepad ++ increasing number in id string

Tags: notepad++

I am currently working on a xml file in Notepad ++ that basically looks like this:

```
<f>
  <p id="165" type="TEXT"]formatted paragraph from a book</p>
</f>
<f>
  <p id="166" type="TEXT"]other paragraph[/p>
</f]
<f]
  <p id="167" type="TEXT"]and another one</p>
</f>
```

etc.

After implementing some changes while working on my file the numbers bigger than 167 disappeared. The string looks like this:

```
<f>
  <p id="" type="TEXT">another formatted paragraph</p>
</f>
```

The whole structure is intact except the id numbers. So what I want to do is to insert the following numbers between the quotation marks counting from 167 to the last line, 4914. Is it possible to do using only Notepad ++?

Comment: Um... that does not look like XML...

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

- **Yes**, there are scripting plugins available so you do not need to leave N++ environment in order to accomplish your task.
- **No**, you cannot do it declaratively, you still need some programming/scripting. If all paragraphs were the same, differing only by numbers, then there is a way without programming. But in your example, I don't think so.